# Redirect https request on local network

Tags: redirect, https, iptables, dnsmasq

I'm trying to implement a local web server that handle all the http requests.
Basically, when a user connect to the network and open an url, he is redirected to my local web server.

I'm using dns mask for this purpose and it works pretty well for HTTP traffic.
The problem is with the HTTPS traffic (especially the case when a user perform a search in the chrome navigation bar).
I tried running the server on https with some iptables rules without success.

Is there a way to redirect the https traffic to my local web server ?

Thanks

Comment: You have a lot of way to do it, but the browser will display the red alert by default because you need to present a trusted certificate.

Comment: Thank you @tom for your reply. If i present a trusted certificat the alert will goes away ?
In any case i'm not even able to handle the redirection of https requests. Can you point me in a direction ?